# how to resize product image before store it into database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to resize image before store it in database.i want to store product image with some product informations .I Have written the code bellow .but still the image size remains same ..how can i fix that in my code?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

 $product=new Product();
 $request->validate([

        'product_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'product_title' => 'required|max:255',
        'category'=>'required|integer',
        'subcategory'=>'required|integer',
        'product_code' => 'required',
        'product_price' => 'required',
        'product_discount' => 'integer',
        'product_color' => 'max:255',
        'product_price'=>'required',
        'product_size'=>'max:255',
        'homepage_visiblity'=>'max:255',
        'homepage_trend'=>'max:255',
        'product_description' =>'required|max:1000',
        'image' => 'required|file|image|max:5000',

        ]);

 $image=$request->file("image");

if($image){



        $image_name=str_random(20);
        $ext=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_full_name=$image_name.'.'.$ext;
        $upload_path='image/';
        $image_url=$upload_path.$image_full_name;
        $image_resize =Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
        $image_resize->resize(20, 100);
        $image->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
        $product->image=$image_url;



        $product->product_name=$request->product_name;
        $product->product_title=$request->product_name;
        $product->category_id=$request->category;
        $product->subcategory_id=$request->subcategory;
        $product->product_code=$request->product_code;
        $product->product_price=$request->product_price;
        $product->product_discount=$request->product_discount;
        $product->product_color=$request->product_color;
        $product->product_price=$request->product_price;
        $product->product_size=$request->product_size;
        $product->homepage_visiblity=$request->homepage_visiblity;
        $product->hot_trend =$request->hot_trend;


        $product->save();
        Session::put('message','Product inserted successfully!!!!');
        return redirect('/product');

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to save the image after resizing it. If you're ok with overwriting the original image file, try this:

`$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(20, 100)->save();`

If you don't want to overwrite the original image file, try this;

`$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(320, 240)->save('public/foo.png');`

*'public/foo.png' should be changed to the desired location, relative to the application root*

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $ext = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $fileNewName = str_random(20) . ".{$ext}";
    $destination = "image";

    $successUpload = $image->move($destination, $fileNewName);

    if($successUpload)
    {
        Image::make($destination . '/' . $fileNewName)->resize(20, 100)->save();
    }

    $product->image = $fileNewName;
    ...
}
```